# UINavigationBar - prefersLargeTitles - How to set image to the left of the title?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

The below article shows how to add an image to the right of the navigation title. 
https://blog.uptech.team/how-to-build-resizing-image-in-navigation-bar-with-large-title-8ba2e8bcb840

I'd like to add the image to the left of the navigation bar title. To achieve it, I set the leftAnchor instead of the right anchor for the imageView like below.

```
imageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: navigationBar.leftAnchor, constant: Const.ImageRightMargin)
```

The image shows above the navigation bar title, which is not what I'm after. I'd like the image to be on the same line as the title (left of the title).

Note:

1. I've seen other questions on SO about adding images to the title
   view    but this question specifically requests information about
   adding    image to the left of the title. Therefore, this question
   is not a    duplicate.
2. I know that I can set a custom title view like below but I do not
   want to lose the prefersLargeTitles setting of the navigation bar.

   self.navigationItem.titleView = customTitleView

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You can't do that without some kind of workaround. One of them being custom title view.

Comment: @Evgeniy - I tried many variations and none of them seem to work. Can you throw some light on the kind of workaround, that you are suggesting?

Comment: I meant implementing custom title view, where you would need to do the large title behavior your self. Or custom navigation bar. Unfortunately, I don't see any easier ways.

Comment: I tried the custom title view. The custom title view label just stays in the center of the navigation bar. I can't get it to the next line in the navigationBar (left aligned) like how the title would look when setting the prefersLargeTitles=true. Any suggestions? Also, do you know how I can achieve this by creating a custom navigation bar? I don't seem to get much documentation on creating a custom navigation bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let img = UIImage.init(named: "imgName")

        let imgView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30))

        imgView.image = img!

        imgView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

        let item = UIBarButtonItem.init(customView: imgView)

        let negativeSpacer = UIBarButtonItem.init(barButtonSystemItem: .fixedSpace, target: nil, action: nil)

        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [negativeSpacer, item]

    }
}
```

The result

[image]

If you want to execute a request when you click the image, replace this line

```
let negativeSpacer = UIBarButtonItem.init(barButtonSystemItem: .fixedSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
```

with that line

```
let negativeSpacer = UIBarButtonItem.init(barButtonSystemItem: .fixedSpace, target: self, action: #selector(go))
```

And place this

```
@objc func go() {

    print("go")
}
```

Comment: prefersLargeTitles should be set to true. That would make the title left aligned and it would overlap with the image.